# Veem to offsite storage fails after 2 hours

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, windows-server

Site A has the Veem application installed on a Windows server.
Site B has Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS with mounted drive as storage location.

Site A to Site B utilizes 1Gig connection over VPN to transfer files.

Windows Firewall and Ubuntu Firewall allow any traffic to one another.

At the 2h 17m mark, the transfer of a 1TB compressed file fails daily with the error message "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host Failed to upload disk".

I have taken a pcap while the backup was running and found that the Veem server at Site A sends an out of sequence packet to which Ubuntu responds by spamming [RST] Packets shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of Wireshark]

I have failed to find a solution to this issue. Neither server uses teamed Nic's or uses the Vqm technology on some Qlogic Nic's. I have ruled out the firewall interrupting the connection as I see no logs on the firewall. Both servers are running on ESXi (Site A ESXi 6.5, Site B ESXi 5.5) This has happened several times at 2h 17m and a few seconds and all captures show the same out of sequence packet.